magento2 custom tab add product grid filter issue
I have faced an issue with the below code. I have removed the below code, and then the working filter is fine, but the page reloads.
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setId('bliss_grid_products');
    $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
    $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
    if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('entity_id')) {
        $this->setDefaultFilter(['in_products' => 1]);
    } else {
        $this->setDefaultFilter(['in_products' => 0]);
    }
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
}


You are checking in Admin grid ?

To fix this issue, update the _construct() method and ensure compatibility with AJAX filtering:
Updated _construct() Code:
protected function _construct()
{
   parent::_construct();
   $this->setId('bliss_grid_products');
   $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
   $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
   $this->setUseAjax(true); // Enable AJAX for the grid

// Only set default filters if no custom filters are applied
if (!$this->getRequest()->getParam('filter')) {
    if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('entity_id')) {
        $this->setDefaultFilter(['in_products' => 1]);
    } else {
        $this->setDefaultFilter(['in_products' => 0]);
    }
}

// Save grid parameters in the session for persistence
$this->setSaveParametersInSession(false); // Disable session save to prevent conflicts

}

Still, I am facing a reload issue.
https://prnt.sc/LD6spPcyRD2q
